# How to print a QR Code using a thermal printer with EPSON commands?

Tags: c#, qr-code, thermal-printer

I need to print a QR Code with a thermal printer, i have tried to use EPSON commands to make it work but it hasn't worked. When i try to print the QR with this code i only get printed the info of the printer. Has anyone deal with a problem like this?

This is the code that i used with no results.

```
var m_encoding = Encoding.Default;
string QRdata = Purchase.TransactionReference.BookingId;
int store_len = QRdata.Length + 3;
byte store_pL = (byte)(store_len % 256);
byte store_pH = (byte)(store_len / 256);


string txt = m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 9 }); //TAB
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 9 }); //TAB
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 9 }); //TAB
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 9 }); //TAB
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, store_pL, store_pH, 49, 80, 48 }); //FUNCTION 80
txt += QRdata;
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, 3, 0, 49, 69, 48 }); //FUNCTION 69
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, 3, 0, 49, 67, 5 }); //FUNCTION 67
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, 4, 0, 49, 65, 50, 0 }); //FUNCTION 65
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 29, 40, 107, 3, 0, 49, 81, 48 }); //FUNCTION 81                        
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 13 }); //CR
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 10 }); //LF
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 10 }); //LF
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 10 }); //LF
txt += m_encoding.GetString(new byte[] { 27, 105 }); //CUT
var resultQR = GenerateStreamFromString(txt);
BinaryReader binaryQR = new BinaryReader(resultQR, Encoding.Default);
port.Write(binaryQR.ReadBytes((int)resultQR.Length), 0, (int)resultQR.Length);
```

Comment: Thermal printers usually use ZPL oe EPL not epson commands (what ever they are)

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation on your printer, and if you have none, contact the manufacturer and ask them for said documentation. we cannot help you

Comment: I've already read the documentation, the POS commands that are in there doesn't work either. The printer is a Toshiba 4610-1NR. BTW.

Comment: I was under the impression that you had to send the functions in ascending order: 165, 167, 169, 180, 181, 182. https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=140

Comment: did you ever get this to work? If yes, can you post your solution?